# Prove or disprove: if $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ is twice differentiable and $f$ and $f'$ are bounded then $f''$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I believe this is not true and I wonder if this is a correct counterexample:
Define $F: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $F(0)=0$ and $F(x)=\sin (1/x)$ elsewhere. Then define $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x} F$. Then $f$ is differentiable and bounded on $(0,1)$ and $f'(x)=\sin (1/x)$. On the other hand, $f''(x)=-(1/x^2) \cos (1/x)$.

Is this counterexample correct and or is there any flaw in my reasoning?

**Is there a function $f$ not defined in terms of integrals which does not satisfy the given property?**

Comment: Your approach isn't bad. You can start with unbounded function and look if its antiderivative is bounded. For example, if you start with something as obvious as $1/x$, you get $\ln x$, which is still unbounded. But in the next iteration you get $x\ln x - x$, which is bounded. Now, ignore $x$ since it has "uninteresting" derivatives and antiderivatives (in a sense that all of them are bounded) and integrate $x\ln x$ to get $\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log (x)-\frac{x^2}{4}$. Again, ignoring "uninteresting" parts, you get $f(x) = x^2 \ln x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=x^{3/2}$ is an example of a fucntion such that $f$ and $f'$ are bounded but $f''$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. Another example would be $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ where $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$.